# Python - df.groupby.sum() returns NaN

Tags: python, group-by

I have a dataset of about 27,00,000 rows as a dataframe in python.
The dataframe has two columns temperature and time spent at that temperature.
I want to groupby temperature and sum the time spent at each temperature.
I used the following code.

df_copy = df.groupby(['Temperature']).sum()

I am getting the summed values for some temperature and NaN for some other values.

There is no NaN values in temperature column or time_spent column.

NOTE: The left column in the image is temperature and the right column is the time_spent in hours.

[image: df with temperature and time spent]

Comment: How we can answer without the data? If there are no NAs we should see the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
There were some inf values in time_spent column.
Rectified those things. Now it is working.